# adding custom horizontal scrollview in all view controllers

Tags: ios, scrollview, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am using a horizontal `scrollview` with some buttons and a search bar.I need to show it in all view controllers .Here is my code

```
for (int i=0;i<[[[xmlSubDictionary objectForKey:@"pillars"]objectForKey:@"pillar"]count];i++) 
{
  [pillarArray addObject:[[[[[xmlSubDictionary objectForKey:@"pillars"]objectForKey:@"pillar"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"pillarName"]objectForKey:@"text"]];

 ///// UIButton* ideaButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*self.scrolView.frame.size.width)/2.5, 3,     self.scrolView.frame.size.width/2.5,40)]; 
  if (i==0)
  { 
    ideaButton.frame = CGRectMake((i*self.scrolView.frame.size.width)/2.5, 3,   self.scrolView.frame.size.width/2.5, 40); 
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scrolView];

    [ideaButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:175 blue:69 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
  } 
 else
 { 
    [ideaButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.42 green:0.42 blue:0.42 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 } 
 [ideaButton setTitle:[[pillarArray objectAtIndex:i] uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 [ideaButton setTag:101+i];    
 [ideaButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionForMealButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
  ideaButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Akkurat-Bold" size:17.0];
  ideaButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
  [self.scrolView addSubview:ideaButton]; 
 }
 [self.scrolView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([pillarArray count] * ((self.view.frame.size.width+200)/([pillarArray count])-5), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrolView.frame))];
```

Comment: Please, format correctly your answer. Can't read your code!

Comment: should i use this method in app delegate class?If yes then how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new subclass of UIView and add your specific code in there. When subclassed, you can use your view in all your viewcontrollers easily.

UIView Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html

Comment: Clicking on button i need to call multiple service call multiple service call.It needs to place of at top of the controller exactly at the navigation bar.In my application there is no navigation bar only that that horizontal scroller consist multiple button and a search bar.

Comment: In my projects I use lots of subclassed views but I try to keep all actions that should perform some further logic in the app to `delegate` calls. Your subclassed UIView should implement delegate logic that can call back on the viewcontroller when a button was clicked, and which button was clicked.

Comment: yes...exactly...should i use scroll view xib for it?

Comment: You can use xib, and using xib will make it easier for you to manage e.g. autolayout. On the contrary  I often write simple UIViews only using code, - no xib, The reason for this is that I then can directly use them in storyboards. I  then override  `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`  for initilaisation.